# Storing a probability for a hashmap value

Tags: java, hashmap, probability

I have a hashmap  where I am reading a text file and storing the unique words into key and the number of frequency of that specific word in another textfile in the value field.

Now, I have to keep track of the probability of the word occurring in another text file. I don't need to know how to calculate the probability, but however, what I need to figure out is, how do I store the probability associated with every key (word) when the value field is already taken (frequency of words).

Do you suggest I make another hashmap with the same keys but replace the values with the probability?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make a class that holds both pieces of information, and store that class in a single hashmap.

Comment: Thankyou Slaks, is there a way without using classes?

Comment: You could just use two hashmaps.

Comment: @Triple777er: Why would you want to avoid classes?  They're designed to hold multiple related pieces of information, which is exactly what you have here!

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be the only solution so far, unless someone else has a better idea.

Comment: @Triple777er There's no better solution, this is the most basic application area for OOP I can even think of.

Comment: @Triple777er What's wrong with making a class for this? If you don't like classes, you could just go back to C, store everything in two arrays and work out your own table lookup. Classes provide abstraction so you don't need to worry about keeping two maps with related keys in sync.